How to prove: $f\equiv0\,(\mathrm{mod}\,p^2)\iff f'\equiv0\,(\mathrm{mod}\,p)$?
Edit: Corrected the mod order.
It might be trivial, but I have no idea at all about it.
For a univariate polynomial $p$, then $f\equiv0\,(\mathrm{mod}\,p^2)\iff f'\equiv0\,(\mathrm{mod}\,p)$
where $f'$ is formal derivative but I will just assume the normal derivative.
i.e., if $p^2$ divides $f$, then $p$ divides $f′$ and so does the converse.
Without knowing number theory, how to understand the following statement using fundamental(high-school) math:

$f$ is square-free (prime) if and only if 1 is a greatest common divisor of the polynomial $p$ and its derivative $f'$.


I think you probably want $f\equiv0,(\mathrm{mod},p^2)\iff f'\equiv0,(\mathrm{mod},p)$? Because "$a$ divides $b$" is $b\equiv0,(\mathrm{mod},a)$.

Isn't $f=(x-1)(x-4)$ and $p=(x-1)(x-2)(x-4)$ a counter example since $f$ divides $p^2$, but $f' = 2x-5$ does not divide $p$?

Also, take $x^2-2x = f$. you have that $x-1$ divides $f' = 2x-2$ but $(x-1)^2$ does not divide $f$

In general, if what you say is true, then $(f')^2$ should always divide $f$ but if $deg(f)>2$ this is never the case

Thank you @Mengchun, it is easier to see with numbers than with functions.

@MathArt No worries, in this case, $\Rightarrow$ is obvious since $f=p^2q\ \Rightarrow f'=2pp'q+p^2q'$, but $\Leftarrow$ does not hold (e.g. $f'=p=3x^2$ but $f=x^3$).

$p(x)=2x+4$ divides $f'(x)=2x+4$ but $p^2(x)=4x^2+16x+16$ does not divide $f(x)=x^2+4x$. Perhaps it is true that $p^2$ divides $f+C$ for some constant $C$ iff $p(x)$ divides $f'$.

I am sorry but I had to downvote and vote-to-close this question as it does not meet MSE Guidelines. There is no context. It also appears poorly thought out, as the straightforward counterexamples in the comments show

Yes, @Mike, I thank you for your comments. I have to confess that I published this cached/saved draft which was poorly thought about because it always stopped me to start any new question.  Another fact is that I immediately become idiot due to arithmophobia or number theory pobia ever since several teachers claimed only talented mathematician can learn number theory well.

@Mengchun, Appreciate your patience to make abstract concrete and easiler to understand... Would you do me a favor how to interpret the 2nd paragraph here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_polynomial?

@MathArt Thanks for the link, to be honest I have no idea how the converse is true, maybe I am missing some conditions on $p$ or $f$? However, the statement "$f$ is square-free $\Leftrightarrow$ $1$ is greatest common divisor of $f$ and $f'$" is true.

@Mengchun, thanks a lot. I will temporarily leave it until in a day I pick up some some basic number theory. Wish all the best to you!

Mengchun Zhang shows in the comments that the forward implication is true, but the reverse is false.
$$
\begin{align*}
f \equiv 0 \mod p^2 
&\implies f = p^2q\\
&\implies f' = 2pp'q + p^2q'\\
&\implies f' = p(2p'q+pq')\\
&\implies f' \equiv 0 \mod p
\end{align*}
$$
They give a counterexample to the reverse implication:  $f'=p = 3x^2$ with $f = x^3$.

OP asks for a double implication.

Oh, I didn't see the comments before posting my answer but I see you and Mengchun answer in the comments.  I will change my answer to CW unless you want to post your comment as an answer.

I think that $3x^2$ divides $x^3$, assuming that the set of coefficients is a field (and $3\neq 0)$. I'm assuming that the set of scalars is a field of characteristic $0$.

@ajotatxe The problem is that $9x^4$ does not divide $x^3$.

These statements are equivalent:

There exists some constant $C$ such that $p^2$ divides $f+C$
There exist some constant $C$ and some polynomial $q$ such that $f+C=qp^2$
There exists some polynomial $q$ such that $f'=q'p^2+2qp'p$
There exists some polynomial $q$ such that $f'=(q'p+2qp')p$
There exist some polynomials $q,r$ such that $r=q'p+2qp'$ and $f'=rp$

And (5) implies that $p$ divides $f'$. But the fact that $f'=rp$ for some polynomial $r$ implies that there exists some polynomial $q$ such that $r=q'p+2qp'$ (which would make the implication reversible) is not true. For example, if $f'(x)=p(x)=x^3$ we get that $1=x^3q'(x)+6x^2q(x)$, which implies that the constant term of $x^3q'(x)+6x^2q(x)$ is $1$, and this is impossible.
Let's try to see for which pairs of polynomials $p,r$ there exists a solution $q$. Let $m=\deg q$ and $n=\deg p$:
Let
$$p(x)=\sum_{j=0}^np_jx^j$$
$$r(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n-1}r_kx^k$$
$$q(x)=\sum_{h=0}^{m}q_hx^h$$
Then
$$p'(x)=\sum_{j=0}^{n-1}(j+1)p_{j+1}x^j$$
$$q'(x)=\sum_{h=0}^{m-1}(h+1)q_{h+1}x^h$$
So,
$$qp'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n-1}\left(\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le k\\k-n \le i\le m-1}}(i+1)p_{k-i}q_{i+1}\right)x^k$$
$$2pq'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{m+n-1}\left(\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le k\\k-n \le i\le m-1}}2(i+1)p_{i+1}q_{k-i}\right)x^k$$
Then, for each $k$, $0\le k\le n+m-1$,
$$r_k=\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le k\\k-n \le i\le m-1}}\left[(i+1)p_{k-i}q_{i+1}+2(i+1)p_{i+1}q_{k-i}\right]$$
$$=\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le m\\k-n+1\le i\le k+1}}\left[ip_{k-i+1}+2(k-i+1)p_{k-i+1}\right]q_i$$
$$=\sum_{\substack{0\le i\le m\\k-n+1\le i\le k+1}}(2k-i+2)p_{k-i+1}q_i$$
This is a linear system for the unknowns $q_i$. It has $m+n$ equations and $m+1$ unknowns, and each equation has at most $\min(m+1,n+1)$ terms. 'Probably' it has no solution. The smaller is $\deg p$, the more probable is that the system has a solution.
Nevertheless, this gives a finite algorithm to decide if there exists $q$ and compute it, but finding a simple, general criterion seems difficult, to say the least.
